# Given a Hessian Matrix find the critical points and classify them

Tags: linear-algebra, hessian-matrix

So I have the following question: Suppose that the Hessian matrix of a certain quadratic form $f(x, y)$ is $ H = \begin{bmatrix} 4 & 8 \\ 8 & 4 \end{bmatrix}$

Find the critical point and the classification of the critical point of f, assume $λ1<λ2$.

So I solved for the eigenvalues of the Hessian Matrix and got 12 and -4. I know he critical point is a relative minimum, however how do I solve for the critical point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look into theorems 3.5 & 3.6 in the link I'm including (Link:http://emp.byui.edu/brownd/mathematics/calculus-rn-rm/hessian-etc.pdf).

These theorems give information on how to use the eigenvalues to determine the concavity of the surface and classify a given critical point. Notice I said "classify" a critical point because the eigenvalues give us no information on the location of the critical points, only whether those critical points would be minima, maxima, or saddle points. You are correct in this case that there should only be one critical point because a positive Hessian implies that $f(x,y)$ is a quadratic polynomial; however, it still doesn't allow us to find the critical point, as there are many possible $f(x,y)$ that would satisfy this Hessian. For example $$f(x,y)= 2(x^2+4xy+y^2)+ax+cy+d$$ would have this Hessian for any constants $a,c,$ and $d$.

Comment: How would I determine the location of the critical point then?

Comment: I don't believe that you can in this case. It comes down to the wording of the question; it doesn't ask what the location(s) of the critical point(s) are, it just asks what you can say about the location(s) based on the Hessian, which is nothing without actually being given $f(x,y)$.

Comment: Ah sorry there was another part I forgot to mention, it says: Find the critical point and the classification of the critical point of f, assume $\lambda_1 < \lambda_2$.

Comment: That's alright, though I would say to edit your question to more precisely fit what you are asking. Well, in this case, you could solve it generally using the equation for $f(x,y)$ I gave in my answer, since that should cover any possible $f(x,y)$. Otherwise, without more information on the specific function the Hessian came from, I don't think you can get a unique answer.

Comment: Yup I edited it. And I feel like 0,0 is just going to be a value that I can enter. We haven't learned this in class and my textbook solutions only give the odd number solutions and this is an even numbered question. Can't find anything similar online either.

Comment: I think $(0,0)$ would most likely be the answer it is looking for and the problem just overlooked that there are other solutions when $a$ or $c$ do  not equal zero.

Comment: Probably is, won't know because the online system I'm using to enter the answer won't let me input a comma. You helped a lot, thank you!